# How to configure postfix to only send to whitelisted addresses?

Tags: postfix, whitelist

I want to configure postfix to only send mail to addresses in a whitelist. I have tried to use `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` in `main.cf` like so:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_unauth_destination
    check_recipient_access hash:/path/to/whitelist
```

The whitelist file is of the format

```
address@example.com    OK
another@example.com    OK
```

And then translated into a hash with the `postmap` command.

Still, the relay is sending mail to non-whitelisted addresses. What am I missing?

*Edit:* I am sending this mail via the `sendmail` command, which apparently bypasses the smptd restrictions. Is there a way to deal with this?

*Edit 2/The rest of the story:* I spent quite a bit of time trying to make sendmail send via SMTP only to discover the command I was using was not sendmail, but postfix's sendmail compatibility interface which mimics functionality but can't be told to use SMTP as far as I could tell.

84104's solution worked perfectly though.

Comment: You need to provide the output of `postconf -n`, so we can see what's real.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You told postfix to reject [some types of mail](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) and accept some other mail. It's possible some messages are not caught be either filter in which case they are permitted.  I think you want to tell it to accept (check) only list and reject all else.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    check_recipient_access hash:/path/to/whitelist
    reject
```

---

in response to edit:
`sendmail(1)` uses `postdrop(1)` not `smtpd(8)`
One way to achieve something like what you're looking for is to manipulate `transport(5)`'s behavior.

```
main.cf
    transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

transport
    address1@domain.tld :
    address2@domain.tld :
    senderaddress@yourdomain.tld :
    * error: Recipient not whitelisted.
```

Note: If you don't include the sender's address in the transport map it will be unable to receive bounce messages.

Comment: That makes sense but does not seem to be my principle problem. If I change it to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject`, it still delivers the mail.

Comment: Using the `transport` method build the hash map with `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport`.